# Parentheses in jqMath lifted up

Tags: mathml, jqmath

In jqMath, if I write a pair of parentheses containing only "short" letters (such as "x"), the result is lifted up from the baseline. See here:

[image: here]

or row 5 in the table at https://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html.

I'm using Chrome 122 on Windows 10.

How can I hack my HTML (or jqMath itself) to make this look OK?

**Edit**: Writing `$f(x)$` in jqMath produces (essentially) `<mrow><mi>f</mi><mrow><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></mrow>` in MathML which renders (badly) as [image: here] in Chrome.

But writing `<mrow><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow>` directly in MathML renders as [image: here] which looks OK.

I don't know which is the "correct" way to write in MathML, but it seems my problem would be solved if I could force jqMath to produce a single `<mrow>`.

Comment: Could this be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Eh, not sure about that. I want to be able to write $(x)$ and have the result on the same baseline as the surrounding text.

Comment: Maybe there is a valid reason that it is written as it is?

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser (chrome, maybe others) bug. See https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40856331.

Comment: Thank you, @davebarton. But is there some hack to make it look OK? Like adding an invisible character of a certain hight and zero width inside the parentheses?

I would really love to start using jqMath, but it's a bit of a deal breaker if parentheses look like this in Chrome.